# carousel controls not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

see my fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/1bc8j418/1/

may b i'm wrong with the code please modify it i was trying different things but failed . thanks for the help!

or you can see the code here

MY HTML

```
<div class="carouselBg">

            <p id="demoSliderFirst" class="textSliders"> 
                Life must be lived forwards, but can only be understood backwards.
            </p>
            <span onclick="prev()">back</span>
            <span onclick="next()">next</span>
        </div>
```

MY JQUERY

```
var demoSlider1 = $('#demoSliderFirst');
var DemoSliderSet1 = [
'Do not dwell in the past, do not dream of the future, concentrate the mind on the present moment',
'What screws us up the most in life is the picture in our head of how it is supposed to be.',
'Life shrinks or expands in proportion to one’s courage.'];
var index1 = 0;

function demoSliderCarousel1(){



    var newDemoSliderSet1 = DemoSliderSet1[index1];

    demoSlider1.fadeOut('400',function(){
        demoSlider1[0].innerHTML = newDemoSliderSet1;
    }).fadeIn('400');


    index1++;

    if(index1 >= DemoSliderSet1.length){
        index1 = 0;
    }

     this.prev = function(){
         if(--this.index1 < 0) this.index = this.DemoSliderSet1.length - 1;
        this.start()
    };

    this.next = function(){
        if(++this.index1 >= this.DemoSliderSet1.length) this.index = 0;
        this.start()
    };

}

setInterval(demoSliderCarousel1,4000);
```

Comment: What is `this.start()`?

Answer (score 0):

You are creating the `next()` and `prev()` functions in the wrong scope. Create the functions outside of the `demoSliderCarousel1()` function and everything is working fine.

```
var demoSlider1 = $('#demoSliderFirst');
var DemoSliderSet1 = [
    'Do not dwell in the past, do not dream of the future, concentrate the mind on the present moment',
    'What screws us up the most in life is the picture in our head of how it is supposed to be.',
    'Life shrinks or expands in proportion to one’s courage.'];
var index1 = 0;

var demoSliderCarousel1 = function() {
    var newDemoSliderSet1 = DemoSliderSet1[index1];

    demoSlider1.fadeOut('400',function(){
        demoSlider1[0].innerHTML = newDemoSliderSet1;
    }).fadeIn('400');


    index1++;

    if(index1 >= DemoSliderSet1.length){
        index1 = 0;
    }
}

var prev = function(){
    if(--index1 < 0) index = DemoSliderSet1.length - 1;
    demoSliderCarousel1();
};

var next = function(){
    if(++index1 >= DemoSliderSet1.length) index = 0;
    demoSliderCarousel1();
};

setInterval(demoSliderCarousel1,4000);
```